# Unable to find remote helper for 'git+https'

Tags: git, composer-php

I get this error every time I try to use the [composer-asset-plugin](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin) from `composer`.

I have read already every single question here related to this problem, but none of those helped. I have `curl`, `zlib` and `expat` installed and I'm using the prebuilt git from my distro (Debian 8), which I'm sure compiles git with https support.

Why is this error happening?

Btw, I noticed that I'm always getting this error when composer (or the plugin, actually) tries to retrieve [angular-toastr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-toastr).

Comment: Cloning from git works ? `git clone https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin`

Comment: @AlexandruGuzinschi The error is thrown by the plugin when it tries to retrieve `angular-toastr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you referenced angular-toastr as npm type and from what I remember it needs to be referenced in composer.json with bower type:

```
"require": {
    "bower-asset/angular-toastr": "dev-master"
}
```

Comment: That indeed was the problem!